# How do I post TouchXML library in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, touchxml, ios5

I want to parse some complected XML files, so I have plan to used TouchXML library ([code](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML))

I used latest version of XCode iOS 5 in ARC environment. But my project already working in non-ARC environment. How do I convert TouchXML classes in non-ARC environment and those should be work in iOS 5. How do I convert it in iOS 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With iOS5 you don't have to use ARC.

[If you use ARC then use the ARC branch.](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML/tree/feature/ARC)

[If you don't use ARC then use the main branch.](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML)

Answer (score 0):

You can download non-ARC version of Touch XML here.
https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML

Comment: yes this link file i using but it gave me 43 error one of the in that is “ARC forbids explicit message send to ‘autorelease’” and “autolrelease is unavailable…” and other on the line  "_node->_private = self" is "Imlicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'void' is disallowed with ARC

Answer (score 0):

I was also using TouchXML until I discovered [RaptureXML](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML). If you're not actually writing to XML and are just parsing and consuming, Rapture is much more lightweight.